# How to read fairly simple JSON file in Delphi Xe4?

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-xe4

I've been struggling with this for a while, and doing something simple seems to be taking too long.

I have a file like this:

```
[
 {
  "FirstName": "Oleg",
  "Surname": "Buckley"
 },
 {
  "FirstName": "Amery",
  "Surname": "Mcmillan"
 },
 {
  "FirstName": "Denton",
  "Surname": "Burnett"
....
```

I want to be able to read them into my program. So far I have worked up this pretty little function:

```
function GetGeneratedNames: TArray<string>;
var fileName: TFileName;
  JSONValue, jv: TJSONValue;
  JSONArray: TJSONArray;
  jo: TJSONObject;
  pair: TJSONPair;
begin
  result := nil;
  filename := ExePath + 'Names.json';
    JSONValue :=  TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TFile.ReadAllText(filename)), 0);
    if JSONValue is TJSONArray then begin
     for jv in (JSONValue as TJSONArray) do begin
       if jv is TJSONObject then begin
         jo := jv as TJSONObject;
         for pair in jo do begin
           Append(result, jo.Value);
         end;
       end;
     end;
   end;
end{ GetGeneratedNames};
```

The trouble is, it returns an array of blank strings. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

TIA
Mark

Comment: Try using `SuperObject` instead - it's a whole world easier.

Comment: `SuperObject` would be as easy as `O.AsArray[jv].S['FirstName']` and `O.AsArray[jv].S['Surname']`

Comment: Can you be more specific. What do you mean by SuperObject? I can't find it in the Embardcadero source.

Comment: That's because it's not part of the Embarcadero source, it's a third-party library

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
// XE5- version
uses System.SysUtils, Data.DBXJSON, System.IOUtils;

function GetGeneratedNames: TArray<string>;
var
  fileName: TFileName;
  JSONValue, jv: TJSONValue;
begin
  fileName := TPath.Combine(ExePath, 'Names.json');
  JSONValue := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TFile.ReadAllText(fileName));
  try
    if JSONValue is TJSONArray then
    begin
      for jv in TJSONArray(JSONValue) do
      begin
        Append(Result, (jv as TJSONObject).Get('FirstName').JSONValue.Value);
        Append(Result, (jv as TJSONObject).Get('Surname').JSONValue.Value);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    JSONValue.Free;
  end;
end { GetGeneratedNames };

// XE6+ version
uses System.SysUtils, System.JSON, System.IOUtils;

function GetGeneratedNames: TArray<string>;
var
  fileName: TFileName;
  JSONValue, jv: TJSONValue;
begin
  fileName := TPath.Combine(ExePath, 'Names.json');
  JSONValue := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TFile.ReadAllText(fileName));
  try
    if JSONValue is TJSONArray then
    begin
      for jv in TJSONArray(JSONValue) do
      begin
        Append(Result, jv.GetValue<string>('FirstName'));
        Append(Result, jv.GetValue<string>('Surname'));
      end;
    end;
  finally
    JSONValue.Free;
  end;
end { GetGeneratedNames };
```

Comment: Ah, the elegance of generics. And the simpler unit name of System.JSON suggests that JSON is seen as more important.

Comment: Fortuately my Xe4 has the same form as the XE5 example. That worked!

Answer (score 5):

You are not reading the correct value from the array items.
Try something like this:

```
//...
var
  JSONArr: TJSONArray;
  Item: TJSONValue;
  FirstName, Surname, WholeObject: String;
begin
  //...
  JSONArr := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TFile.ReadAllText(filename)), 0);
  try
    for Item in JSONArr do
    begin
      // Get the first or last names
      FirstName := (Item as TJSONObject).GetValue('FirstName').Value;
      Surname := (Item as TJSONObject).GetValue('Surname').Value;
      // Get the whole string {"FirstName": "Oleg", "Surname": "Buckley"}
      WholeObject := Item.ToString; 
    end;
  finally
    JSONArr.Free;
  end;
  // do something with them ...
end;
```

The JSON object contains value pairs, but it doesn't have a value itself, so you get empty strings. If you want the whole object text you should use the "ToString" method.

And indeed [SuperObject](https://code.google.com/p/superobject/) or [XSuperObject](https://code.google.com/p/x-superobject/) are easier to use and faster if you happen to work with a large amount of data. The second one seems to also be available for iOS/Android, although I haven't used it.

Comment: That code looks nice and readable. Where does JSONArr come from though? It doesn't get assigned.

Comment: `JSONValue` is actually supposed to be `JSONArr`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to tz and VGeorgiev. Here is the final form of the code, based closely on yours:

```
function GetGeneratedNames: TArray<string>;
var data: TBytes;
    JSONValue, jv: TJSONValue;
    joName: TJSONObject;
    firstName, surname: string;
begin
  result := nil;
  data := TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TFile.ReadAllText(ExePath + 'Names.json'));
  JSONValue := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(data, 0);
  for jv in JSONValue as TJSONArray do begin  // Returns TJSONValue
    joName := jv as TJSONObject;
    firstName := joName.Get('FirstName').JSONValue.Value;
    surname := joName.Get('Surname').JSONValue.Value;
    Append(Result, surname + ', ' + firstName);
  end{for};
end{ GetGeneratedNames};
```